# Add Result of Function to String As Variable - SAM Broadcaster

Tags: delphi, function, variables, pascal

I have a function to grab a random URL.

```
FUNCTION randurl : String;
BEGIN
  // Randomize URL
  Rx2 := RandomInt(4);
  if (Rx = 0) then
    result := 'www.site1.com'
  else if (Rx2 = 1) then
    result := 'www.site2.com'
  else if (Rx2 = 2) then
    result := 'www.site3.com'
  else if (Rx2 = 3) then
    result := 'www.site4.com';
END;
```

I have a string being compiled...

```
var     Rx2 : integer;

{Declaration (Functions and Procedures)}
// Construct the GET String for the Web Script, call it and return the output
PROCEDURE update(status : String); forward;

BEGIN
    // Message to display in twitter
    statusmessage :=  '#Nowplaying ' + Song['artist'] + ' - ' + Song['title'] + ' @ ' + $FUNCTION_OUTPUT_VARIABLE + ' #' + Song['genre'];
    update(statusmessage);
  END;
END;
```

Where $FUNCTION_OUTPUT_VARIABLE is above, I need the random URL to be included. How to I call the function and then insert the output on each pass of the code?

Many thanks!

Edit:

Here's the solution I went with using the above function.

```
{Declaration (Variables)}

var     Rx2 : integer;

FUNCTION randurl : String; forward;

  BEGIN
    // Message to display in twitter
    statusmessage :=  '#Nowplaying ' + Song['artist'] + ' - ' + Song['title'] + ' @ ' + randurl + ' #' + Song['genre'];
    update(statusmessage);
  END;
END;
```

Comment: This is not Delphi. What is it?

Comment: It's PAL, a language from SAM Broadcaster based on Pascal/Delphi. It has bespoke objects but many similarities. I'm not a coder, but as far as I know, grabbing a function as a variable in a string follows  the same syntax/methodology. What you are looking at here is a concatenate. I just want to drop in the result of the stated function as a variable on each pass. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean you can't just replace $FUNCTION_OUTPUT_VARIABLE with randurl ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm a noob. I just need help with the syntax:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the language PAL, here are two variants of how it would work in Delphi:

First:

```
var
  tmp: String;
begin
    tmp := randurl;
    statusmessage := '#Nowplaying ' + Song['artist'] + ' - ' + Song['title'] + 
      ' @ ' + tmp + ' #' + Song['genre'];

    update(statusmessage);
  end;
end;
```

Second:

```
begin
    statusmessage := '#Nowplaying ' + Song['artist'] + ' - ' + Song['title'] + 
      ' @ ' + randurl + ' #' + Song['genre'];

    update(statusmessage);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I tried the second one, which makes sense to me. But it says "unknown name randurl". Do I have to call the function first? how do I do that?

Comment: OK I got it. I used the second solution and defined the function at the start of the script. I'll add my solution above. Thanks!

Comment: In delphi, you need to define a procedure first, before you can call it. You can either include the unit under `interface` or `implementation` when working with classes, or use `forward` to define a forward declaration.

Comment: Yeah I used forward in the end:)